# how to use np.diff with reference point in python

Tags: python, pandas, diff, np

I have a dataset given with time stamps.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['1992-01-01', '1992-02-01',
                                             '1992-03-01', '1992-04-01',
                                             '1992-05-01']),
                      'sales': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                      'price': [4302, 4323, 4199, 4397, 4159]})
```

I am trying to differencing them with `np.diff(data['price'])` for `price` column. However, I want to have a reference point for the first row with timestamp, `1992-01-01`.
My `reference value is 4100` and I expect to have dataset given below:

```
    date,   sales,   diff_price
1992-01-01,  10,      4302-4100 
1992-02-01,  20,      4323-4302
1992-03-01,  30,      4199-4323
1992-04-01,  40,      4397-4199
1992-05-01,  50,      4159-4397
```

Is there any easy way to do it without changing the structure of data in a pythonic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `prepend` parameter of [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to set the reference value (4100) at the beginning of the Series:

```
reference_value = 4100
data['diff_price'] = np.diff(data['price'], prepend=reference_value)
```

or we can [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) with a `fill_value` of the reference (4100) and subtract:

```
reference_value = 4100
data['diff_price'] = (
        data['price'] - data['price'].shift(fill_value=reference_value)
)
```

Either approach produces `data`:

```
        date  sales  price  diff_price
0 1992-01-01     10   4302         202
1 1992-02-01     20   4323          21
2 1992-03-01     30   4199        -124
3 1992-04-01     40   4397         198
4 1992-05-01     50   4159        -238
```